# XSLT - display child elements in a row

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XSLT code that displays movie information from a local XML file (title, actors, runtime, etc.) and Amazon API product information
(product title and picture) from external amazon xml.

```
<xsl:variable name="moviesXML" select="document('movies.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="inputRoot" select="/"/>

<xsl:param name="movieID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Movie details</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="$moviesXML/movies/movie[@movieID=$movieID]">
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                <xsl:value-of select="actors" />
                ...
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$inputRoot/aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:ItemAttributes/aws:Title"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$inputRoot/aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:MediumImage/aws:URL"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aws:Title">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aws:URL">
    <img src="{.}"/>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

So based on the movieID that was passed from the previous page, the code above displays all the relevant information to that specific movie.
I use Amazon API to display two products for each movie (DVD and BluRay product).

The problem I have is that my XSLT displays both Amazon product titles at once and then displays both pictures at once. But what I want is to display
Amazon product title + picture (DVD), and then another Amazon product title + picture (BluRay).

This is the output that I get:

[image: bad]

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image: good]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting what you're asking for.  These lines

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$inputRoot/aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:ItemAttributes/aws:Title"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$inputRoot/aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:MediumImage/aws:URL"/>
```

will first apply one batch of templates, then the other.

You need to put the title and image together in a single template, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="aws:Item">
    <xsl:value-of select="aws:ItemAttributes/aws:Title" />
    <br/>

    <img src="{aws:MediumImage/aws:URL}"/>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then use it like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$inputRoot/aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item"/>
```

Incidentally, this is my first time to see "too much" template decomposition in XSLT code here.  More often you'll see the opposite problem.

Comment: that's perfect! Thank you for your help, harpo. It all makes perfect sense the way you've explained it.